# Is there a Linux input event code that represents a "click"?

Tags: configuration, mouse

I'm configuring my Logitech MX Anywhere with [logiops](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops) and I remember that I used to map one of the buttons to <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> when I used my mouse in Windows, so I could quickly open a link in a new tab in my browser.

Now, the [config file](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops/blob/master/logid.example.cfg) for this program requires users to inform a sequence of keys via their names in the [input event codes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h). I tried searching for "CLICK", but there's only a <kbd>SND_CLICK</kbd>, which definitely isn't the one (especially when it's at the *end* of the file).

While no expert, I kinda expect it **not** to have a "click" event code: from what I infer the list relates only to actual ***physical*** keys available in keyboards. But would that be the case, is there an alternative to achieve a similar behaviour I'm aiming for with the input event codes?

---

### Edit

As per [waltinator's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11135/waltinator) suggestion, running `xev -event button -event keyboard` gives the following output when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x8600001,
    root 0xdd, subw 0x0, time 23492174, (68,103), root:(1752,593),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ButtonPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x8600001,
    root 0xdd, subw 0x0, time 23492917, (68,103), root:(1752,593),
    state 0x14, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x8600001,
    root 0xdd, subw 0x0, time 23492965, (68,103), root:(1752,593),
    state 0x114, button 1, same_screen YES

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x8600001,
    root 0xdd, subw 0x0, time 23493501, (68,103), root:(1752,593),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Maybe [`BTN_LEFT`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L355)?

Comment: Oh, close, but the program makes it fall back only to BTN_LEFT, unfortunately.

Comment: Read `man xev`, run `xev`, then click your mouse button, and see the events.

Comment: Generally speaking, no, there probably is not. A "click" is really a sequence of two events (the exact names depend on he tools you are using): BUTTON_1_DOWN followed by BUTTON_1_UP, or similar. If it only sent one event, applications (or he OS) could not detect things like "drag and drop"--how else could it know if "click" means "holding the button and dragging?" So when searching for documentation/help, keep this in mind.